# Reading HttpContent from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponsemessage

I am sending `HttpResponseMessage` as following from My API controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
        var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("----------");
        bool folderExists = Directory.Exists(path);
        if (!folderExists)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        string pathWithFileName = Path.Combine(path, file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(pathWithFileName);

        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created;
        response.Content = new StringContent(pathWithFileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        response.Content = new JsonContent(new
        {
            Name = "a",
            Address = "b",
            Message = "Any Message" 
        });   

        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return response;
    }
}
```

I am trying to read contents as following

1 - Created an extension method

```
public static string ContentToString(this HttpContent httpContent)
{
    var readAsStringAsync = httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return readAsStringAsync.Result;
}
```

Read contents as following

```
var av = result.Content.ContentToString();
```

Output

```
{"result":null,"targetUrl":null,"success":true,"error":null,"unAuthorizedRequest":false,"__abp":true}
```

Why I don't get contents?
Please advise.

Comment: Sidenote: This is the first time I see an extension method that uses a blocking call to .Result on a Task. You really should not do that, have the extension method return a Task so it can be properly awaited.

Comment: That said, what does "unAuthorizedRequest" mean in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Since the call `httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()` returns a `Task<string>`, I recommend adding an awaiter like the following:

```
public static string ContentToString(this HttpContent httpContent)
{
    var readAsStringAsync = httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return readAsStringAsync;
}
```

Alternately, update your calling code to handle `async` calls so it can just `await` the `ReadAsStringAsync` method directly.